# How to know inside a filter whenever a request is a mapped servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I'd like to know, inside a Filter doFilter method, whenever a request is for a mapped servlet in my web.xml. Is there anyway to do so?

Thanks in advance,

Fernando

Comment: There isn't any way for you to figure it out unless you check the source code of your container (and your solution would be container specific). One possible solution is to parse your web.xml file and on every request check if the URL matches any of the URLs in there.

Comment: thanks! And is there any way to configure a filter just for mapped servlets or it is just for url patterns?

Comment: You would have to do as @balusc has said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can't be done. Better map the filter on those servlets directly. This can be done by using `<servlet-name>` instead of `<url-pattern>`. It has to be exactly that `<servlet-name>` which is definied in the `<servlet>` entries. You can specify multiple if you need.

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>myOneServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-name>myOtherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-name>myLastServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or when you're already on Java EE 6 /Servlet 3.0 and are thus likely using [`@WebFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) on the class.

```
@WebFilter(servletNames={"myOneServlet", "myOtherServlet", "myLastServlet"})
```